# How to find out a String is Arithmetic progression(AP) or not

Tags: java, string

My string is "2358132235".i need to find out whether this is string numbers are making an arithmetic progression or not.I can do it till 8 but when i reached at 13 i don't know hoe to handle multi digits here.Can someone help.Thanks.

private static boolean arthmetic(String s) {
        int i=0;

```
for(i = 0 ; i <s.length()-2; i++)
        {
            int c = s.charAt(i)-'0';
            int c1 = s.charAt(i+1)-'0' ;
            int c2 = s.charAt(i+2)-'0' ;
            if(c + c1 != c2)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

            return true;

    }
```

I know this code is incorrect because it just works till 8

Comment: You're going to need to write a rudimentary parser which knows how to look ahead if the immediate next digit can't satisfy the requirements of a progression.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen How to do that.Can you elaborate by code

Comment: @PalkiDutta - Sorry, but asking people here to write your code for you is  discouraged.

Comment: @Stepehen C sorry but i meant by example.By mistake i wrote code

Answer (score 1):

To solve this you'll write a parser that checks to see if each possible substring can be a progression. We'll assume that the progression is always positive.

Let's demonstrate by using an example with a simpler version of your reference string, "235813". The parser might build the following tokenizations:

- `["2"]`, `["2", "3"]`, `["2", "3", "5"]`; **reject** since 5-3 != 3-2
- `["2"]`, `["2", "35"]`, `["2", "35", "81"]`; **reject** since 81-35 != 35-2 [note: we didn't use `["2", "35", "8"]` because we assume progressions are always positive]
- `["2"]`, `["2", "358"]`; **reject** because the remaining digits can't make a larger number than `358`
- `["23"]` `["23", "58"]`; **reject** because the remaining digits can't make a larger number than `58`

There are no more possible substrings to use for an arithmetic progression. Therefore, this string is not an arithmetic progression. Your parser can also apply the same logic to your longer reference string.

Answer (score 0):

### Check if it matches the expected progression

Once you've decided on what the first two numbers are (2 and 3 in your example, but worth noting that it's ambiguous, you could have a progression string "10011002100310041005" from 1001 and 1002, or "1224364" from 1 and 22), you generate a sufficiently long string with that progression, how it should be - and then compare it against what you were given.